# Ubuntu runs on one toughbook CF-53 but not on an identical machine

Tags: boot

I have lots of Toughbook CF-53's. I have successfully installed Ubuntu 18 on several, but others fail to boot, instead throwing a "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device..." error.
I have tried to research this issue with no success (and and applied at least one 'install grub' fix that didn't work for me).
I suspect it is something to do with the BIOS? and/or the MBR/Grub Boot loader--but I am not experienced enough to figure it out. Please help point me in the right directon!

Model CF-53jjczy1m
Intel Core I5
BIOS v2.00L12

Comment: Are you sure you're installing the grub/boot to the correct device when doing the install?

Comment: I have done the install on all machines exactly the same, I am never prompted about installing Grub--so I am under the assumption it is installed in the same place. If I take the hard drive from a "non working" machine and install it in a "working machine" it boots fine. I looked for an option during install about installing grub--no dice :(

Comment: I have installed MX on the "unbootable" machines with success... what is the clue here?